# How can I redirect to aspxerrorpath with custom error page?

Tags: asp.net

I have a custom error page. I want redirect to that, if an error occurs. Also I want to give the custom error page an referer parameter.

For example I get an Error here:

```
www.example.com/default.aspx
```

I want to redirect to this:

```
www.example.com/error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/default.aspx
```

I can refresh with meta refresh in error.aspx:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://www.example.com/default.aspx">
```

But I want to refresh dynamicly, not just default.aspx

```
--> aspxerrorpath=/THISPAGE.aspx
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try redirect through the web.config setting

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="~/Forms/Errors/Page_404.aspx" mode="On">
<error statusCode="500" redirect="~/servererror.aspx" />
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/NoAccess.htm" />
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Forms/Errors/Page_404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Or You can capture all the exception in the Global.aspx and do the redirect there

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

    Server.Transfer("~/DefaultErrorPage.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`Response.Redirect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). That's what you're looking for.

From the Documentation:

> The Redirect method causes the browser to redirect the client to a
>   different URL.

Also take a look at [`HttpRequest.Url`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the current Url.